# Make top of position from associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$top = array( 'John' => '23.4', 'Andrew' => '12.3' , 'Eric' => '15', 'Will' => '10');
```

How I can get position by numeric value?

Ex: John will get position 4 because have high value

Eric get position 3.....

I want to find position of key by value!

Comment: Sounds like you want to sort the data by the value, keeping the keys.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

Comment: I want to order all by numeric value, then I want to find position of Eric by ex.

Comment: `asort($top); echo array_search('Eric', array_keys($top));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it like below,

```
<?php
function find_rank($name){
   $top = array( 'John' => '23.4', 'Andrew' => '12.3' , 'Eric' => '15', 'Will' => '10');
   asort($top);
   return array_search($name,array_keys($top))+1; # array index starts from zero that's why added extra 1
}

echo find_rank('John');
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/8rp95

Answer (score 0):

This is not correct way to handle this but if you really have to deal with it here is a dirty painful to read code

```
asort($top);
$top = array_flip(array_values(array_flip($top)));
echo $top['Eric']; // will result 2 (list starts from 0 maybe you would like to +1 to result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
asort($top);
$top = array_combine(range(1, count(array_keys($top))), array_keys($top));

echo $eric= array_search('Eric', $top); // return 3
```